# reachabilityWithAddress is not working in Objective C programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, reachability

I want to check a server is live or not with ip, for example, **74.125.71.104 (Google's ip)**

// allocate a reachability object

```
`struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(80);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.71.104");`

Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&address];
```

but those not working.

When I change to `reachabilityWithHostname`, it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please import `#include <arpa/inet.h>`

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(8080);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("216.58.199.174"); //google ip
self.internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&address];
[self.internetReachability startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.internetReachability];
```

**EDIT**

As per your comments your reachability blocks are not called. I always use notifications not much aware of reachability blocks. So I prefer using notifications as follow.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(8080);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("216.58.199.174");
self.internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&address];
[self.internetReachability startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.internetReachability];
```

Now whenever your internet status changes reachabilityChanged method will be triggerred with reachability instance :)

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note {
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:curReach];
}
```

Finally implement updateInterfaceWithReachability as

```
- (void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachability *)reachability {
   NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
            switch (netStatus)
            {
                case NotReachable: {
                    //not reachable
                }
                break;
                case ReachableViaWWAN:
                case ReachableViaWiFi:        {
                    //reachable via either 3g or wifi
                }
                break;
            }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just be aware that some mobile providers have done away with iPv4 and nat everything over IPv6 and then static IP addresses might not work.

Comment: @rckoenes : Bingo :)

Comment: Reachability *internetReachableFoo= [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"74.125.71.104"];
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
        });
    };
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
        });
    };
    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
    My blocks are never called

Comment: As you said you are using delegate pattern, should i conform to any protocol

Comment: @sowjanya-lankisetty : Sorry I used the wrong word delegate :) Its not a delegate pattern its notification pattern that am using :) If you see I have added a notification to kReachabilityChangedNotification. Whenever network status changes you will recieve the notification :)

Comment: @sowjanya-lankisetty : Thanks for pointing out typo :) I have updated my answer :)

Comment: Code flow is working, i added above snippet. But when i am checking for not reachable ip it is showing as it can be reachable, even for the ip which i cant ping from terminal. Check this with any ip that is not in your connectivity range.

Comment: on MAC Device.I am writing this for MAC Desktop app not for iOS

Comment: @sowjanya-lankisetty : I did little bit of search and figured out using reachabilityWithHostName gives wrong status for ip. Lemme update the working code with ip :)

Comment: @sowjanya-lankisetty : Have a look at the updated code :) Tried pinging valid google ip got correct status when tried pinging not reachable ip gave status as not connected

Comment: I am going to case ReachableViaWiFi: when i am giving not reachable ip. I followed your instructions as it is, dont know why this happening.

Comment: Could you please upvote my question @SandeepBhandari, so that we can continue discussion in chat

Comment: @sowjanya-lankisetty : I did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114339/discussion-between-sowjanya-lankisetty-and-sandeep-bhandari).