# iOS 10 Reachability reachabilityForLocalWifi

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, bonjour

I want to check connection to a local wifi with bonjour using `[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWifi]` but it is now deprecated in iOS 10. Apple suggested to use `[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:]` but it still returns "not reachable" even when i'm connected to a local wifi.

update: 
Here is my code using `reachabilityWithAddress` which always returns "not reachable" for local wifi.

```
+(BOOL)checkWifiConnectionIfOn{
    BOOL isOn;

    struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
    bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
    localWifiAddress.sin_len = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
    localWifiAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0.
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM);

    Reachability* returnValue = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:(struct sockaddr_in *) &localWifiAddress];
    if (returnValue != NULL && [returnValue currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable) //Reachable
    {
        //
        isOn = YES;
    }
    else{ // Not Reachable
        NSString *log = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WifiController checkWifiConnectionIfOn Wifi OFF"];
        [Logger writeDeviceLog:log logType:ERROR_LOG];

        isOn = NO;

    }
    return isOn;
}
```

Comment: [have you checked here ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742367/reachabilitywithaddress-is-not-working-in-objective-c-programming).

Comment: @vaibhav i have. i have updated my question to include my code.

Comment: try turning off the wifi and data then try.

Comment: I tried turning off wifi and data, It responds `Not Reachable`. however, what i want is when I am connected to a local wifi (not internet), my method `checkWifiConnectionIfOn` should return `Reachable`

Comment: I ended up changing the requirement for this. have not found any workaround that works for me.